# node-ts shows "error TS2304: Cannot find name '__DEV__'"

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

I recently added `__DEV__` to some TypeScript file in my NodeJS project. In VSCode, this is not marked as an error.

However, when I run the project, I immediately get the error

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name '__DEV__'.
```

I tried adding `/* global __DEV__ */` to the top of the file. Error still there.

I tried adding a `global.d.ts` file where I `declare var __DEV__: boolean;`. Error still there.

Here's my tsconfig:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es6",
  "lib": [
   "es2017","es2015","dom","es6"
  ],
  "module": "commonjs",
  "outDir": "./",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "strict": false,
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
  "downlevelIteration": true
 },
 "include": [
  "**.ts"
 ],
 "exclude": [
  "node_modules"
 ]
}
```

**EDIT:** The project is launched via a `launch.json` file in VSCode. Here's its contents:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Current TS File",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": ["${relativeFile}"],
            "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy", "-r", "ts-node/register", "--max-old-space-size=32768"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "skipFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
                "<node_internals/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You left out the most important information. _How_ are you running the project? What arguments are you passing to `ts-node`? Also, your `tsconfig.json` has a syntax error because it isn't valid JSON which will cause some tools to fail.

Comment: @AluanHaddad See edits. `tsconfig.json` should now be valid json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the only thing that really worked was moving the `__DEV__` variable to an `eval`:

```
const isInDebugMode = () => {
  return eval('__DEV__');
}
```

Not ideal, but it did the job.

The declaration in `index.d.ts` does only resolve the design-time error. The runtime error is not affected by it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a caveat regarding to typing which is officially expressed on the repo https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#help-my-types-are-missing.

To sump up, you can resolve the problem by doing things as following:

Create the structure for `typings` dir like this:

```
- tsconfig.json
- typings
-- global
--- index.d.ts
```

with the `index.d.ts` is your content:

```
declare var __DEV__: boolean
```

Then add `typeRoots` to your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots" : ["./node_modules/@types", "./typings"]
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work. However, it does not answer why `__DEV__` is missing at all. Should not `__DEV__` be a defined variable in all NodeJS environments?

Comment: I don't think so that var is defined by default. I would say you can use `process.env.NODE_ENV` instead